# Okay, so I have a question regarding quotations and commas

Tags: grammar, punctuation, british-english, commas, quotes

Basically I was writing a small prompt about relationships and was thinking about the general rules (I mean professionally writing not in the British way), you put a comma inside quotation of a quote but outside for a phrase if I’m not wrong. So here’s what I wrote: [[ there’s the phrase, “there’s plenty more fish in the sea”, ]] You get the point, I wasn’t clear whether that saying is a phrase or a quote and also if the comma goes inside the quotation. Thanks otherwise.

Comment: It's not clear if you're talking about UK style or not. In UK style, the comma only goes inside the quotation mark in two circumstances: it's part of what's being quoted, or it's the final part of a quoted sentence, and the it makes within the surrounding text.

Comment: Ohh my apologies, for your information I am an Asian-American, and this question had bothered me because whenever I wrote essays (middle school or even high school), I was confused and left punctuations outside of quotes unless included in the quote itself. But none of the teachers really clarified or elaborated on my mistakes until I read a news article and saw the way they wrote (I never read a chapter book), thus is why I asked here instead, but thanks for the clarification, this will definitely alleviate my problems for my future writing in college.

Answer (score 1):

If you are British, the comma goes **outside of the quotations (in this case).**  If you are American, the comma goes **inside of the quotations (in every case).**

---

*In British English, commas are only written inside quotations if they were **in the original quote.***  Also, you place a comma at the end of a quote if you are quoting a whole sentence (this doesn't apply to this case but is still worth mentioning).  In this case, the original quote was just:

> There's plenty more fish in the sea [no comma]

so the comma goes outside of the quotations.

---

*In American English, commas are **always** written inside quotations,* regardless of whether it was there in the original quote.

Comment: This is not entirely true. See page 16 of the [University of Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf). You can put a comma inside the final quotation mark even if it's not in what's being quoted, if what's being quoted is a complete sentence, and the comma makes sense with respect to the final sentence. For example: *'‘Bob likes cheese,’ I said.* It's a complete sentence being quoted, but the speech tag goes ***inside*** the quotation mark. This is a specific exception.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for correcting me; I am American, so the only rule that I knew of was the one that I wrote about.  I'll correct it right now.

Comment: It's a subtle exception to the rule that most people aren't aware of.